# Find all nonnegative integer solutions to $2^a 3^b 5^c - 7^d 9^e 11^f = 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> Find all nonnegative integer solutions to $2^a 3^b 5^c - 7^d 9^e 11^f = 4$.

I think the only solutions are trivial solutions. The tuple $(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (0,1,1,0,0,1)$ is a trivial solution. It could be useful to consider the equation modulo $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.$ It could also be useful to find the orders of some numbers modulo some primes. In particular, there's this theorem that states that if $a^b \equiv a^c\mod d$ for some nonzero integer d coprime to a, then $\mathrm{ord}_d(a)$ divides $b-c$.

Considering the equation modulo 2, if $a>0$, then the LHS is odd while the RHS is even, which is a contradiction. **Hence** $a=0$, so we can ignore the $2^a$ term.

Considering the equation modulo 3, if $b>0,$ then $-7^d 9^e 11^f \equiv 1\mod 3.$ In particular, $e=0$. So $-(-1)^f \equiv 1\mod 3$, which implies that f must be odd. Now if $b=0$, then $(-1)^c - 9^e (-1)^f \equiv 1\mod 3$. In particular, if $e>0$, then $c$ is even. If $e=0$, then c is odd and f is even. Considering the equation modulo 4, $(-1)^b - (-1)^d (-1)^f \equiv 0\mod 4.$ Since $(-1)^x - (-1)^y\in \{-2,2,0\}$ for all x,y, where $-2$ is obtained if $x$ is odd and y is even, 2 is obtained if x is even and y is odd, and 0 is obtained if x and y have the same parity, we know that $b$ and $d+f$ must have the same parity.

Considering the equation modulo 5, if $c>0$, we get $-2^d (-1)^e \equiv -1\mod 5.$ Now the powers of 2 modulo 5 are $2,4,3,1.$ So if $e$ is even, then $d$ is divisible by 4. If $e$ is odd, then $d\equiv 2\mod 4$. If $c=0$, then we get $(-2)^b-2^d (-1)^e \equiv -1\mod 5.$

Considering the equation modulo 6, we get $3^b (-1)^c - 3^e (-1)^f \equiv 4\mod 6.$ But the powers of $3$ are all congruent to $3$ modulo 6, so assuming both b and e are positive, the expression on the LHS must be congruent to one of $-3+3, -3-3, 3+3, 3-3$, all of which equal $0$ modulo $6$. Hence one of $b$ and $e$ has to be zero. If $b=0$, then we get $(-1)^c - 3^e (-1)^f \equiv 4\mod 6,$ so $e=0$ gives $(-1)^c - (-1)^f \equiv -2\mod 6,$ which implies that $c$ is odd and f is even. $e>0$ gives $(-1)^c - 3(-1)^f \equiv -2\mod 6$, so if $f$ is even, then c is even and if f is odd, then $c$ is even. **We deduce** that $b=0$ or $e=0$.

Considering the equation modulo 7, we get $3^b (-2)^c - 7^d 2^e 4^f \equiv 4\mod 7.$ If $d > 0,$ then $3^b (-2)^c \equiv 4\mod 7$.

Considering the equation modulo 8, we get $3^b (-3)^c - (-1)^d 3^f \equiv 4\mod 8.$ Now the powers of $3$ modulo 8 starting with $3$ are congruent to $3,1.$

Considering the equation modulo 9, we get $3^b 5^c - (-2)^d 9^e 2^f \equiv 4\mod 9.$

A lot of the above congruences seem to lead to complicated equations; only considering the equation modulo 2 and modulo 6 led to particularly simple results.

Comment: $125 - 121 = 4 \; \;$  ////  $ 81 - 77 = 4 \; \; $

Comment: not quite   $25  - 21 = 4$   because $21 = 3 \cdot 7$   is not a multiple of $9$

Comment: Brute force search finds $(0,0,1,0,0,0)$, $(0,0,3,0,0,2)$, $(0,1,1,0,0,1)$ and $(0,4,0,1,0,1)$

Comment: @Sil what was your method for the brute-force?

Comment: The fact that $b = 0$ or $e = 0$ can be obtained faster by seeing that if both of them were positive, then $4$ would be a multiple of $3$, which is impossible.

Comment: @NaitikMundra Just a check of all $a=0$ and $b,c,d,e,f\leq 20$ in Maple, it's in no way exhaustive

Comment: The mod $7$ equation with $d \geq 1$ gives $b = c+4 \mod 6$ (using that $5$ is the inverse of $3$ and that $4 = -3$ so everything becomes powers of $3$), while mod $9$ with $e \geq 1$ grants $c = 4 \mod 6$ (by checking powers of $5$), thus we can't have $d \geq 1$ and $e \geq 1$ since that'd mean $b = 0 = c + 4 \mod 6 = 2 \mod 6$, contradiction. In case that helps.

Comment: Commenting so I can work on later

Comment: The mod $8$ equation with $e \geq 1$ is, thanks to $d = 0$ and $c$ being even, $3^c - 3^f = 4 \mod 8$, which is absurd since the possibilities are $1-3$, $3-3$, $3-1$ and $1-1$, none of them being $4 \mod 8$, so $e = 0$. (But I don't know if I should make my comments into an answer, even a partial one, just yet considering the equation is still not solved and I could have made some mistakes)

Comment: One last thing I have: if $b = 0$, then, since the mod $3$ equation gives $c$ even and $f$ odd as noted already, $d$ must be equal to $0$ due to what I said with $b = c+4 \mod 6$ when $d \geq 1$, hence when $b = 0$ the problem becomes: $5^c - 11^f = 4$. And checking that equation mod $11$ grants $c = 3 \mod 10$ when $f \geq 1$.

Comment: (Just realised a small typo: I meant $c$ odd and $f$ even.)

Comment: mod $7$ when $b = 0$ gives (after checking all possible cases) that either $c = 3 \mod 6$ and $f = 2 \mod 6$, or $c = 1 \mod 6$ and $f = 0 \mod 6$ ($c = 5 \mod 6$ and $f = 4 \mod 6$ are impossible).

Comment: When  $(a,b,d,e)=(0,0,0,0)$, eqaution reduced to $5^c-11^f=4$. We can take the three cases $c=3q,c=3q+1$, and $c=3q+2$.
 It can be reduced to finding the integer points on elliptic curves    $y^2 = x^3-4, y^2 = x^3-100$, and $y^2 = x^3-2500$ and we get two solutions $(c,f)=(1,0),(3,2)$.